# Streaming from gstreamer to omxplayer

Tags: streaming-video, streaming, omxplayer

I am trying to set up a stream between two raspberry pi's. However my problem lies with omxplayer as I have to use it and when ever I try to look at a stream I just get "have a nice day"

I have tried:

```
raspivid -t 0 -h 720 -w 1080 -fps 25 -hf -b 2000000 -o - \
    | gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse !  \
    rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! \
    tcpserversink host=YOUR_RPI_IP_ADDRESS port=5000
```

And on the other pi:

```
rtsp://ip_here:5000
```

and

```
rtp://ip_here:5000
```

on omxplayer

Comment: I'm presuming `YOUR_RPI_IP_ADDRESS` is the correct IP used by that pi?

Comment: @goldilocks yes that is correct